# how to insert images dynamically in php from mysql database into a jquery slider

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I have written a page that displays images in a list style with a jquery slider added to it. However, what i need help with is for the jquery slider to recognizes it as a list of images so that the slider can work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Below is my code:

```
<div id="slideshow">
                    <ul class="slides">                 
                    <?php 
                        $target = "admin/photogallery/";
                        $getImages = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photogallery");
                        if(!$getImages) die("Cannot execute query. " . mysql_error());

                        $target = "admin/photogallery/";
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getImages)){
                        if (file_exists($target)) {
                            print '"<li><img src="http://localhost/crystalvirgins/admin/photogallery/'.$row_rsphotogallery['photo'].'" border="0" width="702" alt="'.$row_rsphotogallery['description'].'" /></li>"
                            <div class="clear_3"></div>';
                            $i++;
                        }
                    }?>
                    </ul>
                    <span class="arrow previous"></span>
                    <span class="arrow next"></span>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

just try this code

```
 <ul>
 <?php 
 $directory = "data/uploads/homegallery/";
 if (glob($directory . "*") != false)
 {
 $filecount = count(glob($directory . "*"));
 }
 else
 {
 } 
 $files_index = glob("data/uploads/"."home"."gallery/*.*");
 for ($i=0; $i<$filecount; $i++)
{
$num2 = $files_index[$i];
?>
<li><img src="<?php echo $num2;?>" width="650" height="276" alt="" /> <?</li>
}?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please include the jQuery Plugin and code being used. Also what does the generated HTML source look like.

Comment: its actually not jquery but javascript and html5. I got the slide script form this link: "http://tutorialzine.com/2010/09/html5-canvas-slideshow-jquery/" I have a database that stores the image names. It is from this database that i want the image scr to pick from.